# Merge arrays of X number of arrays of objects with single common key in ES6

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

So I have multiple objects in array that follow patter similar to the following.

Length of all arrays of objects is always the same. `yX`(there can be even like 100 yX(es) and also like 100s of x-y pairs in each array of objects. yX is different but always starting at 0 and is incremented by 1 (y0, y1, y2, y3, y4, ...).

```
const data = [
[{x: 0, y0: 1}, {x: 1, y0: 2}, {x: 2, y0: 3}],
[{x: 0, y1: 2}, {x: 1, y1: 3}, {x: 2, y1: 5}],
[{x: 0, y2: 1}, {x: 1, y2: 2}, {x: 2, y2: 3}]
]
```

How to merge them easily so I can get result like this?

```
const newData = [
{x: 0, y0: 1, y1: 2, y0: 1},
{x: 1, y0: 2, y1: 3, y2: 2},
{x: 2: y0: 3, y1: 5, y2: 3}
]
```

There is probably some simple solution to this that I can't find, but I got lost on this with all different combinations of `forEach`, `.map`, `Object.assign()`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could merge the arrays and get all properties of the same index.

```js
const
    data = [
        [{ x: 0, y0: 1 }, { x: 1, y0: 2 }, { x: 2, y0: 3 }],
        [{ x: 0, y1: 2 }, { x: 1, y1: 3 }, { x: 2, y1: 5 }],
        [{ x: 0, y2: 1 }, { x: 1, y2: 2 }, { x: 2, y2: 3 }]
    ],
    result = data.reduce((r, a) => a.map((o, i) => ({ ...r[i], ...o })), []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: How elegant solution, thanks! Can you give little explanation what's going on during that reduce/map?

Comment: reduce iterates the outer array and wile you need a single array with objects, you need a mapping. this happens with the inner arrays and it takes the array/objects from the last iteration and combines the last obejct with the acual one.